# How do I properly combine several loss functions that have a different shape in CNTK?

Tags: cntk

In CNTK, I'd like to combine several loss functions that have a different shape. The loss I’d like to use has four parts, each contributes a gradient for training the network:

```
loss = rpn_loss_cls + rpn_loss_bbox + loss_cls + loss_bbox
```

where the individual shapes are

```
rpn_loss_cls: (33489,1)
rpn_loss_bbox: (33489,1)
loss_cls: (100,1)
loss_cls: (100,1)
```

Obviously I can’t just add them up, do I have to stack them using ‘splice’ before passing the loss to the trainer? Do we have a Python example that does that already?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce_sum` or `reduce_mean` with `all_axes()` or `all_static_axes()` to make each loss a scalar, then combine them as you wish.